# How to filter a list using "like" operator with a parameter in a REST aplication?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, date, url

I'm building a web application using REST; more specifically, Node.js. So far, I've had no problems formatting the URL (using `?` and `&` operators; `limit` and `skip` to filter fields, for example).

Now, I need to filter a list of Sensor Readings to show only the data that was inserted in a specific day.

The date is being stored as a String in MongoDB in the format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss", or "25/04/2017 10:20:56". The reason I'm storing it as a String rather than as datetime is because it takes less space, as there's limitations of storage in the project.

Using the "like" operator in the URL (`%`, that is), I've successfully managed to filter some other String fields, such as `/sensorReading/?deviceNum=MBA%`. However, when I try to filter the date String, it fails.

I've tried in many different ways, but nothing is working, even when I don't use the like operator and put the full string (space is being replaced as %20):

```
/sensorReading/?dateString=13%
/sensorReading/?dateString=1%
/sensorReading/?dateString=%1%
/sensorReading?dateString=1%
/sensorReading/?dateString=13/04/2017%2012:57:16
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the '/' character present in the String, to separate day, month and year.

Is there a way to do this via URL, or will I have to do it in the front end of my aplication? For the front, I'm using JavaScript and AngularJS.

Comment: so you're querying the db directly based off of your url?  That doesn't seem secure...

Comment: The query isn't shown; it loads a view that returns the result. This is in the code only.

Comment: Then I'm struggling to see the problem. You can pass whatever parameters you like as long as you know how to break them down into a meaningful query on the other side.

Comment: You're not reading the question. Sure, I _can_ pass the parameters on the query, but the query _isn't_ working with this field.

Comment: And you haven't posted a very clear question.  There is no query here.  Are you talking about the ***querystring***?  How does that correlate? Regardless, your immediate solution is that you should probably url encode the parameter before adding it to the querystring since it contains special characters and you should decode it on the other side.